# How to use Nest API version 1.1

Tags: nest-api

Is there a secret to updating a client to use the new API version (1.1 announced today)? My requests (REST) are still returning the version 1 results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation released with the update today: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/client-version

You need to:

> 1. Visit the Clients page and select the edit gear icon in the client summary
> 2. Select [Change permissions] and select [Yes] to confirm the change
> 3. Select [Update client]
>
>    That's it, you're done!

Comment: The end user also has to approve the update in the Nest app (mobile or presumably web)

Comment: End user approving updates is only applicable if the permissions are actually changed (IE: Add or removal of any permissions). Following the instructions above merely updates the API version to get access to new fields that fit into current permissions schemes.

Comment: This process also isn't working for me; humidity doesn't show up even after performing the steps above.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a new client before I could see the new data fields